# Lazy Load with Scrollable {Virtual:true} not working in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am facing an issue to implement lazy loading in kendo ui grid.
I added scrollable virtual property and backend server side code to handle it but issues is after adding scrollable property I am unable to see scroll bar in my Grid. 
Even the selected rows (20 page size) disappears off the bottom of the grid into the hidden overflow area.

Here is my code.

```
var managecustomerGrid = $("#customerGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        schema: {
            data: "results",
            total : "totalRecords",
            model: {
                id: "SRNUMBER",
                fields: {
                    SRNUMBER : {type: 'number'},
                    CUSTOMERNAME : {type: 'string'},
                    DATEPAID : {type: 'string'}
                }
            }
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        batch: false,
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/customer/customer.cfc",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (xhr, error) {
                    alert('Error In Getting Customer Information.');
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, type) {
                return {
                    ntPageNumber: options.page,
                    ntRowLimit: options.pageSize,
                    vcSortOrder: JSON.stringify(options.sort),
                    vcFilterCondition: JSON.stringify(options.filter)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    height: 600,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    },
    filterable: {
        operators: {
            string: {
                    contains: "Contains",
                    startswith: "Starts with",
                    endswith: "Ends with",
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    doesnotcontain: "Doesn't contain"
            }
        }
    },
    sortable: true,
    columns: [      
        { field: "SRNUMBER", title: "SR No.", width: "80px", template: "<span id='#=SRNUMBER#'>#=SRNUMBER#</span>"},
        { field: "CUSTOMERNAME", title: "Customer Name", width: "110px"},
        { field: "DATEPAID", title: "Date", width: "110px"},
        { command: ["edit","detail","cancel"], title: "&nbsp;",  title: "Actions", width: "130px", filterable: false, sortable: false}
    ]
});
```

Please let me know if any one find any issues. I am unable to get it.

Answer (score 0):

The kendo grid does not really support Lazy Loading out of the box. It may be easier to instead just make a blank scroll-able grid (without paging), and then to populate the data with ajax calls. You can use $.merge() to append data to the data array with little to no impact on performance.

```
$.ajax({
url: '/getNextData',
data: { filter: 'foo', lastLoaded: $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.at($("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total()-1).ID },
dataType: "json",
success: function (newData) {
    $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data($.merge($("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(), newData))
},
error: function (e) { console.log(e); }
});
```

In this ajax example I load the next data based on the current last item in the grid and a filter. I just append the response to the currently loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, my problem was the controller code. Here I am posting my controller hoping it would help someone someday

```
 public JsonResult GetJson(int? projectid,int skip, int take, int pageSize, int page)
    {

        using (sqlCon)
        {
            var myData = sqlCon.Query<Device>("Select  * from workbook.dbo.TargetList", new { projectid = projectid });
            var data = myData .Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            var total = myData .Count();
            var json = new { data = myData };
            var jsonResult = Json(new {data= data, total= total}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }

    }
```